# take information from a CSV file in Perl

Tags: perl

what is the most simple code in Perl that can go through a CSV file and create math calculation?
to be more concrete:
i have a CSV file that contains:

```
Input       Execution       Output  Total
608         124800          1856    127264
512         124960          1920    127392
864         124992          1888    127744
```

and I want to calculate the standard deviation of each column. (for the input\exection\output\total)
lets assume this file is under : `myDocuments\me\info.csv`

I have succeeded in writing a function that loops the csv file and calculate the standard deviation of column Input. but if I want it to be a general function that I can call from several places in the code that receives a string like "Input" or "exection" for which the function should be doing the calcs to - how do I do that?

Comment: Is your input a CSV file? It looks like you have it in columns. What's the math you're doing? Is this your output? What does your input look like? What math do you want to perform? How much Perl do you know? I make a living writing Perl scripts. I'll be glad to do the job at my standard rate of $115/hour.

Comment: just do some research how to slurp a text file and parse out delimited fields.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'sum';

my @data;
while (<DATA>) {
  push @data, [ split ];
}

my $headers = shift @data;
my $n = @data;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#{$data[0]} ) {

  my $mean = sum(map $_->[$i], @data) / $n;
  my $stddev = sqrt(sum(map { ($_->[$i] - $mean) ** 2 } @data) / $n );

  printf "%-9s: Mean %.3f,  Standard Deviation %.3f\n",
      $headers->[$i], $mean, $stddev;
}


__DATA__
Input       Execution       Output  Total
608         124800          1856    127264
512         124960          1920    127392
864         124992          1888    127744
```

**output**

```
Input    : Mean 661.333,  Standard Deviation 148.569
Execution: Mean 124917.333,  Standard Deviation 83.989
Output   : Mean 1888.000,  Standard Deviation 26.128
Total    : Mean 127466.667,  Standard Deviation 202.947
```

Comment: wow , this looks so cpmlicated... what do you think of my code?

Comment: Your code doesn't process the data you showed in your question, and it calculates the stats for only the first column. My code does several steps in a single statement so it may be more compact than you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Most people just cobble up a parser using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), but the quick and robust [wheel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) already exists for parsing and generating CSV (and tab-separated data).

But what you ask about and what you have appear to be different things. What you posted isn't a CSV, and Text::CSV_XS won't do it. But really, it's quite simple.

You can parse the line using

```
my @fields = split(' ', $line);
```

And you can recreate the file (if necessary) using

```
printf($fh "%-11d %-15d %-7d %d\n", @fields);
```

---

So your question is not about operating on arbitrary columns. That means you need to have columns of data that can be accessed by name. That yells for a hash of array..

```
 my $headers = <$fh>;
 my @headers = split ' ', $header;

 my %data;
 while (<$fh>) {
    my @row = split;
    for (0..$#header) {
       push @{ $data{ $headers[$_] } }, $row[$_];
    }
 }

 some_func( @{ $data{Execution} } );
```

Comment: i have succeded in writing a functino that loops the csv file and calculate the standard deviation of column Input. but if i want it to be a general function that i can call from severl placed in the code that recives a string like "Input" or "exection" for which the function should be doing the calcs to - how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
the function is:
 sub parse_standard 
{

    my $filename = "myDocuments\\me\\info.csv";
        #first, calculate the Avg and the number of rows
    open(INPUT, $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename";

    # Read the header line.
    my $line = <INPUT>;
    my $sum = 0 ;
    my $counter = 0;
    #Read the lines one by one.
    while($line = <INPUT>)
    {
        chomp($line);
        my ($Input,$Execution,$Output,$Total,$SelfTest,$Log_Location,$Log_Name) = split(',', $line);
        $sum = $sum + $Input;
        $counter = $counter +1;

    }

    $avg = $sum / $counter ;
#second ,  calculate the standard deviation
    open(INPUT, $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename";
    my $line = <INPUT>;
    my $sum = 0 ;
    #Read the lines one by one.
    while($line = <INPUT>)
    {
        chomp($line);
        my ($Input,$Execution,$Output,$Total,$SelfTest,$Log_Location,$Log_Name) = split(',', $line);
        $diff = ($Input-$avg);      
        $square = $diff * $diff ;       
        $sum = $sum + $square;

    }

    $tosqrt = $sum / $counter;
    $answer = sqrt($tosqrt);
    print "standard deviation is $answer\n";
    close(INPUT);
}

parse_standard();
```